# Got killed too early while running selenium Firefox /usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 181: 9173 Killed DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1

Tags: linux, selenium, centos, headless-browser, xvfb

I'm running selenium headless Firefox browser using xvfb-run on Centos. The problem is that the process gets killed too early while tests are being run. The process is killed unexpectedly at a random test step.

I have run other headless browser tests on the same linux machine using the same xvfb-run command without issue. I ensure that there are still remaining web driver instances running not all the sessions are closed.

/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0, 1280x1024x24"

I expect the process is killed after all the tests are finished. Not to be killed while a test is being run.

Comment: Error stack trace please...

Comment: You do not need xvfb for running the Firefox in headless mode . Just pass --headless  argument while starting the Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode

Comment: Is there any output upon termination?